# Java, SWT, make the window (shell) transparent in part

Tags: java, swt

I have a similar example like this:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0300__SWT-2D-Graphics/CreatefilledrectanglesusingthefillRectanglemethods.htm

All I want to do now is make that red rectangle "punch out" the window, so that I can see what is behind it

Comment: You can create a `Shell` in a custom shape like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTShellcreateanonrectangularwindow.htm).

Comment: how? how? how? how? (sorry it didnt let me type one time)

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted?

Comment: Yes, the blue "this" in my comment is called a link ;) Well, here you go again: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTShellcreateanonrectangularwindow.htm

Comment: AAAHH YYEEESSS that link was visited before, has "grey blue" color so I didnt realize it was a link. Yes, I saw that example, but it uses a reversed approach - full transparent window, and draw something on it. I want it just reverse

Comment: and how can it make it antialiased? (Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options, for a java solution: Use the javax robot package to screenshot and use it on the background... It's not ideal and if the window moves, the background changes? But anyway, the true solution would be to use JNI to make the actual API calls. Check out the Java Runtime Source on OpenJDK to see how the AWT interfaces with its supported Operating Systems. Window opacity is a gimmick and a sign of poor design. If you're too inexperienced with C/C++ or any other native interface language, I defer you to [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), or idealistically [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/). Which are prebuilt/packaged JNI bindings for (as GL implies) OpenGL.

Comment: JOGL isn't a second class citizen, it can be used with SWT by several ways, with or without the SWT AWT bridge, it provides a heavyweight SWT GLCanvas and a NEWT SWT canvas (NewtCanvasSWT). The word "idealistically" has nothing to do here.

Comment: Except it does; I have experience with both and in every instance I encounter, LWJGL has executed more quickly, has less memory overhead, has been far simpler in implementation, and their bug-resolution has provided fixes in a much more timely manner... An ideal satisfies ones concept of perfection; thus the reasons I just listed make it ideal to me... The speaker. Your comment is frivilous.

Comment: I have used JOGL since 2006, I'm an engineer in computer science, anybody can find my curriculum vitae, I have worked on several applications mixing 2D and 3D, with Swing, AWT, SWT, Eclipse RCP and recently Netbeans Platform. Both have similar performance especially when they are used with their respective native windowing toolkits. They both use JNI under the hood, they can't have very different speeds. Its "simpler" implementation leads to drastic limitations, you can't create multiple Display instances without having an error (except in v3) and it has a worse integration of AWT and SWT.

Comment: I qualify for Mega-Society and have managed the worlds LARGEST and  MOST utilized infrastructure for > 6 years! But what does that matter? Are we measuring ego's or helping someone? Citing credentials to prove one's validity is magnanimous with not having any. Point is, using SWT in your reply proved your inexperience;  SWT is a framework built atop AWT, of which, LWJGL binds without issue. This is preferential conjecture, arguably pointless. JNI under the hood? Yes, somewhat. JOGL has a heavyweight java binding atop of its JNI roots. That's why it is arguably slower.

Comment: SWT isn't built on top of AWT, which is quite helpful to support AWT-less environments, for example on mobile phones. Look at the source code of SWT, it doesn't use AWT at all, it's a complete alternative. LWJGL AWTGLCanvas is known not to be very reliable, it's not because of its maintainers, it's because JAWT was very obscure until a few years ago whereas JOGL was a Sun project when JOGL AWT GLCanvas had been implemented. Both JogAmp and its competitor contain a Java binding for the OpenGL API that relies on JNI to call native OpenGL methods and I don't see why JOGL would be heavyweight.

Comment: I challenge you to find at least one evidence that "SWT is a framework built atop AWT". It's completely wrong.

Comment: Done, took 3 seconds. class javax.swing.JFrame extends java.awt.Frame, class javax.swing.JComponent
extends java.awt.Container. So seriously, are you that certain? You're just wrong. I mean it is LITERALLY built atop  AWT; by its very definition for code-sakes.

Comment: You make a confusion between Swing (javax.swing, in the standard JDK) and SWT (org.eclipse.swt, not in the standard JDK). Swing uses AWT but SWT does NOT use AWT (even though it has a bridge called SWT_AWT). SWT is here: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ I didn't expect such a big mistake.